# Call a function in a variable?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a search form made for wordpress (in another php file)

```
function search_form {
    echo '<form>code</form>';
}
$search_form = search_form();
```

I want this:

```
if('true' == $instance['example'] )
    echo '<div>' . $search_form . '</div>';
```

How can i do this because with the example above does not work.

Answer (score 2):

```
function search_form {
  return '<form>code</form>';
}
$search_form = search_form();
```

Use `return` instead of `echo`

Answer (score -1):

use `$form = get_search_form(false)` to get the search form in variable.

Example:

```
$form = get_search_form(false);
if('true' == $instance['example'] )
echo '<div>' . $form . '</div>';
```

read more on get_search_form [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_search_form)

Comment: Not what i was looking for but thanks...i've made a 'fix' !